# Random battery Macbook issue from 22% to full charge

Tags: battery, macbook, battery-life, macbook-pro-retina

After the battery replacement and an SMC and PRAM reset, still I'm getting strange behaviors on the new battery.

I have been working the MacBook for some time, and after having 82% of charge it shutdowns to 0%. Then I start charging the battery and when it arrives to 22% it changes to full charged. I don't understand what should be the cause, the problem is that my first battery replacement was doing the same faults and the second one got the same issues.

Any ideas what could be wrong? I have some thoughts that the battery is not the issue but something else, but who knows.

MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015)- 2.5 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i7

I use the original charger that came on the MacBook, an 60W MagSafe 2.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What battery did you put in as a replacement? It sounds like the new battery is faulty.

Comment: It's a Simplo battery, the replacements are from two different suppliers but same brand.